# How to connect web socket protocol using socket.io in android

Tags: android, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to establish a communication between my server and my application using `socket.io`. But it shows that `socket.io` can't connect to a server having `ws` protocol.

My server url is something like -->

`ws://dev1.geobit.siliconorchard.com:3366/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket`

And my code is:

```
private Socket mSocket;

{
    try {
        IO.Options opts = new IO.Options();
        opts.transports = new String[]{ WebSocket.NAME};
        mSocket = IO.socket(new URI(Constant.WEB_SOCKET),opts);

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public Socket getSocket() {
    return mSocket;
}
```

This shows the **error** of

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.dev.quras.application.QurasApplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.URISyntaxException: unknown protocol: ws: ws://dev1.geobit.siliconorchard.com:3366/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket"

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I used Okhttp for this:

```
private fun loggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor =
        HttpLoggingInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor
                .Logger { message -> Timber.tag("OkHttp").d(message) })
                .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)

private val okHttp = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor())
        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
```

Then you can start a websocket like this:

```
val listener = SocketListener()
val request = Request.Builder()
                        .url("${socketURL}?access_token=${token()}")
                        .build()

val socket = okHttp.newWebSocket(request, listener)
```

Listener class example:

```
class SocketListener() : WebSocketListener() {

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket?, text: String?) {
        try {
            val json = JSONObject(text)
            val payload = json.getJSONObject("payload")
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket?, code: Int, reason: String?) {
        webSocket?.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS, null)
    }

    companion object {
        private const val NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000
    }
}
```

Comment: I very much appreciate your answer, but i was looking for the way to connect a server having ws protocol with socket.io. can you please help me in this process?